# Multiples of an effective degree 2 divisor on a hyperelliptic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $L$ denote the Riemann-Roch space, and $l$ its dimension.

We are given the following definition:
A curve $C$ of genus $g$ is hyperelliptic if and only if there is a degree 2 divisor $D$ such that $l(D)\ge2$

In that case, without loss
of generality we may assume $D$ is effective and that $L(D) = (1,x)$ where $(...)$ denotes span and $x$ is nonconstant.

I need to prove that $L(nD)=(1,x,x^2,...,x^n)$ for $n\le g-1$. The $\supseteq$ direction is easy.
Using ultrametric absolute values, I've shown that $1,x,...,x^n$ are linearly independent. It remains to show that $l(nD)\le n+1$, which is what I'm having trouble with. I went to my professor and was given a hint to use Riemann-Roch Theorem, but I can't figure out how to obtain that bound. Here's what I have.

Let $W$ be a canonical divisor. Then $l(nD)-l(W-nD)=2n-g+1\le n+1$ for $g\ge n$. Since $l(W-nD)\ge0$, I don't have an upper bound on $l(nD)$. If someone can help, that would be great. Thanks.

I've shown that $(g-1)D$ is canonical, but I can't use that since my proof involves the assumption that $l(nD)=n+1$.

Comment: does anyone have a different way to prove the other direction $L(nD)\subseteq (1,x,...,x^n)$? Any help will be appreciated. Or if the result is false, could anyone provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I think this comes down to a pigeonhole principle argument. First, note that (I think) you've shown that $x^n \in L(nD) \setminus L((n-1)D)$ for $n \leq g$ (see the discussion in the comments). Thus
$$
\ell(nD) - \ell((n-1)D) \geq 1
$$
for all $n \geq 1$, i.e., each time we increase $n$, the dimension has to go up by at least $1$. Now since $\deg(gD) = 2g > 2g - 2$, then $\deg(K - gD) < 0$, so
$$
\require{cancel}
\ell(gD) - \cancelto{0}{\ell(K - gD)} = 1 - g + \deg(gD) = 1 - g + 2g = g+1
$$
by Riemann-Roch. Here's a table of the values $\ell(nD)$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\ell(D) & \ell(2D) & \ell(3D) & \cdots & \ell((g-1)D) & \ell(gD)\\ \hline
2 & ? & ? & \cdots & ? & g+1
\end{array}
$$
Thus $\ell(2D) < \ell(3D) < \cdots < \ell((g-1)D)$ is a strictly increasing sequence of $g-2$ values chosen from the set $\{3, 4, \ldots, g\}$. But $\{3, 4, \ldots, g\}$ only contains $g-2$ distinct values, so there's only way this can occur: we must have
$$
\ell(2D) = 3, \ell(3D) = 4, \ldots, \ell((g-1)D) = g \, ,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Your claim that $x^n\notin L((n-1)D)$ is only true for $n\le g$. Indeed, otherwise $x^{n+1}\in L(nD), ..., x^{g+1}\in L(gD)$, which is impossible since $l(gD)<g+2$. However, that's sufficient to complete your argument.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, especially your sentence starting with "Indeed", which seems to say exactly the opposite of my claim. $x^n \in L(nD) \setminus L((n-1)D)$ for all $n \geq 1$, not just $n \leq g$. The divisor of poles of $x^n$ is $nD$, so $(n-1)D + \operatorname{div}(x)$ is not $\geq 0$.

Comment: Can you tell me why the divisor of poles of $x^n$ is $nD$. Take $n=1$ for instance. Let $D=P+Q$, with $P,Q\in C$. How do you know $\text{div} x$ is not something like $-P+R$, where $R\neq P,Q$, so then its divisors of poles is $P$, not $P+Q$.

Comment: The "Indeed" is starting a proof by contradiction. I increased $n$ to $n+1,...$ and so on up to $g$, so my proof would not work if $n>g$.

Comment: If $P\neq Q$, then one of $P,Q$ have negative order on $x$, so  $x^n$ would have order $-n$ at that point, and that works. Problem arises when $P=Q$, if $x$ has an order of $-1$ on $P$ rather than $-2$.

Comment: So, your "Indeed" sentence is just proving the claim for $n \leq g$? Okay, but that doesn't make my claim false. Just because your proof only shows the result of $n \leq g$ doesn't mean it isn't true for all $n$.

Comment: I'm beginning to get very suspicious of your definition of hyperelliptic. Is $\mathbb{P}^1$ hyperelliptic? By your definition, it seems to be. $\mathbb{P}^1$ has $k(x)$ as its function field. Let $D = 2 \infty$ (where $\infty = [1:0]$). Then $L(2\infty)$ has basis $1, x, x^2$, so $\ell(D) \geq 2$.

Comment: As to why $x$ couldn't have a pole at just $P$: I would usually say that that would mean that $x^{-1}(\infty) = \{P\}$, so $x$ would be a degree $1$ map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then $x$ is an isomorphism (assuming $C$ is nonsingular), so $C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Usually I would say this is a contradiction, but if you consider $\mathbb{P}^1$ to be hyperelliptic then I guess it isn't... Often hyperelliptic curves are assumed to have genus $\geq 2$, or at least $\geq 1$.

Comment: All right, if genus $0$ curves are hyperelliptic by your definition, I agree with your stipulation that $n \leq g$. I've edited to that effect. Thanks for pointing out this subtlety.

Comment: this is my prof's definition on our homework. No I didn't say you are wrong, just "not necessarily" right since you didn't prove it.